# Any online collaborative drawing/diagramming/brainstorming tools that support freehand drawing as well as shapes?

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, drawing, diagram

I have looked at several tools - draw.io, gliffy, lucidcharts.  None support freehand drawing.

I know there are several online whiteboards, but I'm looking for something more sophisticated.

should have:

- both shapes and allow free-hand drawing
- collaboration
- private drawings
- ability to save diagrams
- ability to export and import diagrams

basically, gliffy or draw.io with freehand capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a **Drawing** type document on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com):

[image]

It has a **Lines** and a **Shapes** menu. Under the first you can find **Scribble** which corresponds to freehand drawing, and under the second you can find common geometric shapes.

- Supports both shapes and freehand drawings
- Supports collaborations with revision history (through Google Drive)
- Drawings are private unless you choose to share them
- Ability to save drawings either on Google Drive or locally
- Exports to `.pdf`, `.svg`, `.png`, and `.jpg`
- No direct import, but you could insert other diagrams as images

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best ones I found so far are Tayasui Sketches and Microsoft OneNote. Both are worth trying but I confess I'm not 100% happy with either of the two.